# How can I keep my biz website with Squarespace but my blog with WordPress

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, dns, squarespace

I started my website with Squarespace, and while it's great for a static small-biz website, it's not working for a dynamic blog. I'd like to start a self-hosted WordPress blog but still keep the domain name as the same for both - www.cooksmarts.com. In my DNS manager, I've mapped my A Record to SS's IP address. How can I change it so that www.cooksmarts.com would take you to SS but www.cooksmarts.com/blog would take to WordPress blog?

Comment: Related: [Can a CNAME DNS record point to a subdirectory?](http://serverfault.com/questions/47175/can-a-cname-dns-record-point-to-a-subdirectory) at ServerFault

Answer (score 1):

I'd [recommend creating a sub-domain](http://css-tricks.com/put-a-subdomain-on-a-different-server/) `blog.mysite.com` and pointing the `A Record` (or possibly a `cname`) for it to an alternative server.